# Save form data with handlebarsjs and marionettejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I'm trying to save the form data to a server using a Deployd API; but when i click the save button, a new document it's created at the server but it contain no data. I don't understand how it can work; i guess i have to pass the data to the model to be saved? How do i do that? I thought that the view was already linked with the template and model.
I'm using Requirejs, MarionetteJS and Handlebars.
Here is the code.

MODEL:

```
define(['underscore','backbone'], function(_, Backbone){
var Student= Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/students',
  defaults: {
     nameStudent: '',
     lastnameStudent: ''
  },
  initialize: function(){
    console.log('studentModel: initiated');
  },
});
return Student;
});
```

VIEW:

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'marionette',
'handlebars',
'js/models/student',
'text!templates/forms/studentFormAdd.html'

], function($, _, Backbone, Marionette, Handlebars, studentModel, studentFormAddTemp){

    var studentFormAdd = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        model: studentModel,
        template: Handlebars.compile(studentFormAddTemp),   
        events: {
            'click #saveBtn': function(){
                this.model.save();          
                console.log(this.model.toJSON());
                console.log('saveBtn event: initiated');
            }
         },
        initialize: function(){
            console.log('studentFormAdd: initiated');
            this.model = new studentModel();
            this.model.on('change', this.render);
        },
    });
```

My template has the following sintax:

```
<div>
<form>
Student Name<br>
<input type="text" name="nameStudent" value="{{nameStudent}}" placeholder="Student name"/>
<br>
Student lastname<br>
<input type="text" name="lastnameStudent" value="{{lastnameStudent}}" placeholder="Student lastname"/><br>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone doesn't use two way binding, so:

```
this.model.save();
```

in your `saveBtn` event handler is empty.  If you want realtime two-way binding, you can use:
https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder or https://github.com/NYTimes/backbone.stickit

If you wan't to simply consume the form data on submit and save it in a model, you can use https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.syphon.

```
 var data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(this);
 this.model.set(data);

 this.model.save();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me! (pun intended)